# Limit of $x[3-\cos(x^2)]$ using the epsilon-delta definition of a limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits-without-lhopital, epsilon-delta

I have been asked to determine the limit $L$ of $x[3-\cos(x^2)]$ for $a=0$, and prove that it is the limit by showing how to find a $\delta$ such that $|f(x)-L|< \epsilon$, $\forall x$ satisfying $0<|x-a|<\delta$.

I understand that by definition $\delta=\min(1,...)$ and that $\delta$ depends on our $\epsilon$.

Thanks!

Comment: So for clarification purposes you are trying to find $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ such that $a=0$ and $f(x):=3x-x\cos(x^2)$?

Comment: @Sentinel135 Yes-

Comment: Have you figured out what $L$ is?

Comment: Ok hint: $L=0$ and set $\delta<\varepsilon/4$. Also Keep in mind that $\cos(x^2)\in [-1,1],\; \forall x \in \mathbb R$.