# Limit of $x[3−\cos(x^2)]$ using the epsilon-delta definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital, epsilon-delta

This is a duplicate of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2173558/limit-of-x3-cosx2-using-the-epsilon-delta-definition-of-a-limit?newreg=e749c6baa0174f70b67e3ec71fe41add) here, but I'm new to Stack Exchange so I'm not able to comment on that post yet (and sorry in advance if this question isn't appropriate to the platform).

I was reading through Spivak's Calculus (4th ed.) and came across Problem 5.3.i asking to "determine the limit *l* for the given *a*, and prove that it is the limit by showing how to find a $\delta$ such that $|f(x)-l|< \epsilon$ for all *x* satisfying $0<|x-a|<\delta$: $f(x)=x[3-cos(x^2)], a=0$. Not sure if my solution is correct, but here's what I have:

I first found the limit by just substituting $0$ into the different parts of the function ($3x$, $x$, $cos(x^2)$) and multiplied and added the limits to get $l=0$.

Then substituting values into $|f(x)-l| < \epsilon$, we obtain $|x[3-cos(x^2)]| < \epsilon$. By properties of absolute values, factor and divide to get $|x|<\frac{\epsilon}{|3-cos(x^2)|}$, and we get desired form of $|x-a|<\delta$ (since $a=0$).

So let $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{|3-cos(x^2)|}$, but since the minimum value of $\delta$ is when the denominator is maximized (so when $cos(x^2) = -1$, we can simplify to $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{4}$, completing the proof.

Is this the proper way to approach the problem, and is the final solution correct? Also, is simplification acceptable in the final step, or does it make the answer less precise?

Comment: This would not be acceptable; your chosen $\delta$ is not allowed to depend on your $x$. (This is discussed a bit more [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2686159/why-cant-delta-depend-on-x-in-delta-epsilon-proofs).)

Comment: @PrincessEev I just read through the thread you provided, thanks! I thought about that problem while writing the solution and was under the impression that making the delta true for all x would solve the problem, but guess not. So would the correct solution not have any x's on the "side" of the epsilon at all?

Comment: Is x2 your way of writing $x^2$? The way to get $x^2$ here is to write x^2 with a dollar sign on each side.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry about that, just fixed it.